# Access the first and/or last item in an bound ArrayList

Tags: asp.net, arraylist, repeater, items

I've got an ArrayList bound to a repeater control. In an associated, but separate, area of the page, I'd like to get the first and last item out of the bound control. It's actually a paging element to a table.

Here is the code for the Repeater:

```
this.Repeater1.DataSource = pagingArray;<br>
this.Repeater1.DataBind();<br>

<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server"><br>
    <ItemTemplate><br>
        <a href="/?page=&lt;%# Container.DataItem %>"><%# Container.DataItem %?</a><br>
    </ItemTemplate><br>
</asp:Repeater><br>
```

I'd like to get the first element from this repeater and display it.  The code that I have right now (that doesn't work) is:

```
<% Response.Write(Repeater1.Items[0].ToString()); %>
```

BTW: I'm a complete .NET newb.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because your `<% Response.Write(Repeater1.Items[0].ToString()); %>` happens before you've bound the repeater. Why not read from the original data source, anyway?

```
<% Response.Write(this.pagingArray.First().ToString()); %>
```

Comment: I didn't know that Response.Write happened before the binding. Thanks. I tried your suggestion and got the error: 'System.Collections.ArrayList' does not contain a definition for 'First'. Any ideas?

Comment: Anything in <% %> tags happens before anything in <%# %> tags.

Comment: Well you can put it back to the array index this.pagingArray[0] - I was thinking in Linq. So if you want to use .First(), just import the System.Data.Linq namespace at the top of your page.